# Configure io.sentry and io.sentry.logback in wildfly 24

Tags: wildfly, sentry

Is there any way to configure io.sentry and io.sentry.logback for wildfly? so my Javaee application can log to sentry through wildfly.

I tried to add io.sentry and io.sentry.logback as modules, but always get
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: io.sentry.logback

I added io.sentry-5.2.0.jar and io.sentry-logback-5.2.0.jar to \modules\system\layers\base\io\sentry\main ...\sentry-logback\main folder with module.xml and tried to configure

```
<custom-handler name="SENTRY" module="io.sentry.logback" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
                <level name="WARN"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] [%t] %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <properties>
                    <property name="dsn" value="https://f455e9b9a2bd47ca8c547f4919178f3b@sentry.uc.se/38"/>
                </properties>
            </custom-handler>
```

in standalone.xml

also added io.sentry and io.sentry.logback jar to module/system/layers/base/io/sentry (sentry-logback)/main

with module.xml. following is xml for sentry.logback

```
<module name="io.sentry.logback" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9">

  <properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
  </properties>

  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sentry-logback-5.2.0.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="io.sentry"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Did you create a module named `io.sentry.logback`?

Comment: yes I did, I added io.sentry and io.sentry.logback jar to \modules\system\layers\base\io\sentry (sentry-logback) /main with module.xml

Comment: Not critical, but it should just be in `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/io..`. Given the name though, it sounds like this is a logback appender which cannot be created as a custom-handler. You'd have to create a `java.util.logging.Handler` which wraps the logback appender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems wildfly is using Log4j so I switched to sentry-jul integration, and it works well after that.

Some guide on sentry github

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/discussions/2129#discussioncomment-3031199